# Searching through list of random files in directory and renaming files based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: Included my code.

I am still relatively new to VBA, so please bear with me:

I am trying to write a code that will go through a folder and loop through all files (file names will be random) and rename them based on a specific cell's value, C12 in my case. To give an example:

If C12 in a file = A, then file name should be 1, if C12 in a file = B, then file name should be 2, if C = 3, and so on.

I have put together the following code:

```
Let Files = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx")

Do While Files <> ""
Set X = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\*.xlsx", True, True)
X.Saved = True

If X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12").Value = "VALUE1" Then
   Name Path & File As Path & NAME1
X.Close

ElseIf X.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12").Value = "VALUE2" Then
    Name Path & File As Path & NAME2
X.Close
End If

File = Dir()

Loop
```

The way I understand it, the code should go through each file (because of `File = Dir()`) , open it and run the IF statement above, rename the file, and then move on to the next file in the directory and do the same. But when I run it, it only opens the same file every time. Any thoughts on why?

Hope that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, from an excellent explanation why it didn't work in this post: [Excel VBA Dir loop fails when open and close command added within loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494212/excel-vba-dir-loop-fails-when-open-and-close-command-added-within-loop)

Added an extra sub as the YowE3K suggested and it works great now!

Answer (score 0):

two files can't have the same name in the same directory so you can't name more than one file as "1" , Do you mean you want to rename the file to what it was before plus a "1"? Assuming you do - and assuming you want to append the 1 to the name and not the extension then

```
Sub RenameFiles
Const dirholdingfiles = "C:\Test"
dim sFileName as string
dim postpend as string
postpend = asc(ucase(range("c12")))-64
sfilename=dir(dirholdingfiles)
do while sfilename <> ""
movefile dirholdingfiles & "\" & sfilename dirholdingfiles & "\" & left(sfilename,len(sfilename)-4) & postpend & right(sfilename,4)
sfilename = dir()
loop
end sub
```

(Written on my phone - not tested, typos likely)

Comment: Hi @Harassed Dad, thank you for your reply. The file name to be saved can be anything (I will choose it myself later), I just meant to give an example that different cases will require a different file name. Apologies if that caused any confusion. Do I understand correctly that the code 'postpend = asc(ucase(range("c12")))-64' sorts the dir by ascending order? And which part of the code sets the conditions for naming, i.e. If Cell C12 is ... , then name should be ...? Thanks.